# Can we write .htaccess for two different dynamic pages like product.php & blog.php in php mysql?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?-([^/]+)? product-details.php?pro_slug=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?-([^/]+)? blog-details.php?n_slug=$1&n_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

this will working for only first defined page product-details.php. please help.

I am hitting on `www.test.com/blog/Want-to-transfer-your-home-loan-to-another-bank`, `www.test.com/product/agriculture-land-near-by-agra`  First url should be served by product-details and 2nd one should be served by blog-details.php file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code. Could you please do mention which URL should be served by `product-details.php` AND which url should be served by `blog-details.php`? Because right now your rules will process any url to `product-details.php` file only.

Comment: You can obviously _not_ use the exact same pattern twice, that simply makes no sense - how should the server know, which of the two cases it is supposed to be in each instance?

Comment: i am using base url for both pages

Comment: i am a new developer so please suggest me the right code.

Comment: @vijay, you need to understand question I asked you in first comment. Let's say you are hitting a url eg: `http://test.com/test123/singh` and `http://test.com/test456/singh` as of now your current rules will always serve any of  these urls to product-details.php file only. So what urls should go to product php and what should go to blog php? If you can't answer this then its impossible to here, sorry.

Comment: please check these ulr's
http://test.com/product/product-details.php
http://test.com/blog/blog-details.php

Comment: @vijay, What URL you will be hitting in browser when you want it to be `test.com/product/product-details.php` in backend?

Comment: I am hitting on 
'www.test.com/product-details.php?pro_slug=?&id=?'
'www.test.com/blog-details.php?n_slug=?&n_id=?'
I want it to be Like this below
'www.test.com/blog/Want-to-transfer-your-home-loan-to-another-bank',
'www.test.com/product/agriculture-land-near-by-agra'

Comment: @vijay Where exactly are the `product-details.php` and `blog-details.php` scripts located? You've referenced both `test.com/product/product-details.php` and `test.com/product-details.php` and also `test.com/blog/blog-details.php` and `test.com/blog-details.php` in comments - please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rule file.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(blog)/([\w-]+)/?$ product-details.php?pro_slug=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(product)/([\w-]+)/?$ blog-details.php?n_slug=$1&n_id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: this code is not working dear, not getting dynamic values on the page after hitting on the url.

Comment: @vijay. I am trying to help you here(we all are), if you don't give us information on what is NOT working and what is working(with samples/examples) then its a waste of time for both of us, please provide more information on same and I could try to help, cheers.

Comment: The last part of the regex `(.*)/?$` will capture the optional trailing slash, which probably is not the intention. You need to make the capturing subpattern non-greedy, eg. `(.*?)/?$` or exclude slashes from the pattern, eg. `([^/]+)/?$`. The filesystem checks could be avoided by just making the regex a bit more specific and omitting the trailing slash (which isn't included in the examples and which could potentially create a duplicate content issue), eg. `([\w-]+)$`.

Comment: @MrWhite, Thank you sir for letting know, edited post now, cheers.

Comment: @vijay, could you please do check these edited rules and let me know if this helps you? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.